# Is the Gensim word2vec model same as the standard model by Mikolov?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am implementing a paper to compare our performance. In the paper, the uathor says

> 300-dimensional pre-trained word2vec vectors (Mikolov et al., 2013)

I am wondering whether the pretrained word2vec Gensim model [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tutorials-run-word2vec-py) is same as the pretrained embeddings on the official [Google site](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) (the GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz file)

My source of doubt arises from this line in Gensim documentation (in Word2Vec Demo section)

> We will fetch the Word2Vec model trained on part of the Google News dataset, covering approximately 3 million words and phrases

Does this mean the model on gensim is not fully trained? Is it different from the official embeddings by Mikolov?

Comment: You can refer to here: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data for where and how the data was taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That demo code for reading word-vectors is downloading the exact same Google-trained `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300` set of vectors. (No one else can try re-training that dataset, because the original corpus of news articles user, over 100B words of training data from around 2013 if I recall correctly, is internal to Google.)

Algorithmically, the `gensim` `Word2Vec` implementation was closely modeled after the `word2vec.c` code released by Google/Mikolov, so should match its results in measurable respects with regard to any newly-trained vectors. (Slight differences in threading approaches may have a slight difference.)